# Positioning of my website header is properly aligned offline but in chrome it aligns incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have a header that is aligned correctly when I view it offline, as well as online using Safari.  When I view it online with chrome it is incorrectly aligned, but if I refresh the page it will then align properly.

Here is the url to the website to observe the issue yourselves: http://viscovisco.com/ (refresh browser to see it fix itself, the issue only seems to happen in chrome).

Also feel free to inspect element. Let me know if you need further information.

Here is the HTML code for the section that seems to be working improperly online:

```
<div class = "container">

    <div id="box1">
        <span id="firstname" onmouseover="nameToMatt()" onmouseout="defaultMode()">VISCO</span>

        <span id="lastname" onmouseover="nameToLexi()" onmouseout="defaultMode()">VISCO</span>

        <br>
        <span id="information"></span>
        <br>
        Design & Programming
    </div>

    <div id="rightBoxes">
        <div id="box2">
            <i>Est.</i> 2014.
            <br>
            Based in SF Bay Area
        </div>

        <div id="box3">
            <div class="letter"> L </div> 510 541 2464
            <br>
            <div class="letter"> M </div> 510 367 6435
        </div>

        <div id="box4">
            Hallo!
            <br>
            projects@viscovisco.com
        </div>  
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the associated CSS:

```
.container {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 18.66px;
    line-height: 22.4px;
    min-width:960px;
}
.container > div {
    display: inline-block;
}

#box1 {
    width: 340px;
}

#rightBoxes {
    float: right;
}

#rightBoxes > div {
    float: left;
}

#box2 {
    margin-right: 45px;
}

#box3 {
    margin-right: 81px;
}
```

Here's a screen shot of both correct and incorrect formatting of the website.  On the left is the incorrect format that I only see on the online website in Chrome broswer when I first open the website.  On the right is the correct format which Chrome switches to if website is refreshed (this format is also seen offline and on Safari):

[image]

(image cuts a bit of the website off, you should be able to see full website and notice the behavior described by clicking the link provided above)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: No difference in my Chrome between first and second load.

Comment: what should it look like?

Comment: I didn't post code because it's fairly easy to inspect element and see the pertinent code but I will add it to help clarify, as well as pictures clearly showing the issue.  I have checked it on 3 different computers chrome browser and the problem still exists.  Pictures and code will be up momentarily, thanks for the help.